# How to use a tensorflow function embedding_lookup properly

Tags: tensorflow

I am doing my deep learning project, and I need to see a value inside the Tensor object, but I can not. How can I print a value of x :  `Tensor("add:0", shape=(1, 25, 128), dtype=float32)`.

This is for test of deep learning algorithm for embedding, and I used python3.7, tensorflow 1.13.1 and keras 2.2.4

```
embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(params['30'],params['128'], embeddings_initializer='glorot_normal') + pos
with tf.Session() as sess:
    try:
        print("check:",tf.nn.embedding_lookup(X_embedded),tf.constant([1][0]).eval(session=sess)))
```

And I put various param in `tf.constant()` like `[0][0][1]` - in this case I got

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

And put `[0][1][0]` - in this case I got

> IndexError: list index out of range

I tried it, because I thought it might start in reversed order.

As I described above when I tried this, its type was `Tensor("add:0", shape=(1, 25, 128), dtype=float32)`.

Thank for your reading!